# Post one item from model collection to controller method in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where I display a list of users, setting the model as:

```
@model List<MyProject.Models.User>
```

In this view I want to be able to choose to perform an action on a specific user, i.e. post to the controller that I want to disable a user. How do I post the specific User object to the controller?

This is what I've got so far, but I can't see how to post the specific object from the collection:

```
@foreach (var c in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@c.Username</td>
        <td>@c.IsEnabled</td>
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("DisableUser", "UserManagement"))
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Disable" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My controller has the signature:

```
public ActionResult DisableUser(User user)
```

Comment: Do not post `User` but rather the ID of the `User`, and use `@using (Html.BeginForm("DisableUser", "UserManagement", new { id = User.ID} ))` to add a route value and use `public ActionResult DisableUser(int ID)`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke your comment was very helpful. Can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than posting back all propeties of `User`, you can just add a route value in the `BeginForm()` method to post back the ID or the User`. Assuming that property is named`UserId`, then

```
@foreach (var c in Model)
{
    <tr>
        ....
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("DisableUser", "UserManagement", new { id = c.UserId ))
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Disable" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

and the controller method would be

```
public ActionResult DisableUser(int id)
{
    // Get the User based on id, update it and redirect
}
```

You could also consider using ajax to submit the value, which would allow the user to stay on the same page and continue to 'disable' other `User` objects without need to make a redirect, in which case the code might be

```
@foreach (var c in Model)
{
    <tr>
        ....
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="disable" data-id="@c.UserId">Disable</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

var url = '@Url.Action("DisableUser", "UserManagement")';
$('.disable').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $.post(url, { id: $(this).data('id') }, function(result) {
        if(result) {
            // for example, remove the row from the table
            row.remove();
        } else {
            // Oops
        }
    }).fail(function (result) {
        // Oops
    });
});
```

and the controller method would be

```
public JsonResult DisableUser(int id)
{
    // Get the User based on id and update it
    return Json(true);
    // or if the update failed - return Json(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to disable a user is to use a Html.ActionLink instead of the form - you should be able to see plenty of examples of this in the template code. The action link could redirect to a confirmation page or you could just disable the user and redirect to a message page saying "the user has been disabled".

I better way is to use AJAX. You can do this with jQuery or you could use the MVC [Ajax form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) or [Ajax Action Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx).  I would recommend that you google MVC Ajax Action Link examples.

You may also want to style the link by setting it's class to the [Bootstrap 'btn' class](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#button-tags).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to post a single user

```
@foreach (var c in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>@c.Username</td>
    <td>@c.IsEnabled</td>
    <td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("DisableUser", "UserManagement"))
        {
           <input type="text" name="Username" value="@c.Username">
            <input type="text" name="IsEnabled" value="@c.IsEnabled">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@c.id">

            <input type="submit" value="Disable" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        }
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

The ideas is same,due to lack of time, please proceed according to your requirements,  use the Class Property name as input name, the action will get the value

Answer (score -1):

First of all you must not declare Html.BeginForm inside of any loop to post the object to controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DisableUser", "UserManagement"))
{
    @foreach (var c in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@c.Username</td>
            <td>@c.IsEnabled</td>
            <td>           
                <input data-id="@c.Id" type="submit" value="Disable" class="clsBtnPost btn btn-primary"/>           
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

This is for your reference

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".clsBtnPost").click(function(){
        var userId = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ControllName/MethodName', //Your Url
        data: { 'userId': userId },
        success: function () {          
           alert("successfully called.");
        },
        failure: function (response) {          
           alert("Error");
        }
      }); 
   });
});
```

You can go with the **Ajax** Call to pass a single object to controller.

Comment: Please someone will let me know -1 for what?

Comment: You have shown an alternative method using ajax which is fine if OP wants to stay on the same page (and perhaps something OP should consider) although it does not directly answer the question. But your statements _you must not declare Html.BeginForm inside of any loop_ (its perfectly fine and common to do that, especially for deleting items in a collection) and _you must go with the Ajax_ are simply wrong. Consider editing your question to remove those statements and note that this is an alternative (and its benefits)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your guidance.